# ibatis, oracle: escaping inside BEGIN/END block

Tags: sql, oracle, date-comparison

```
<select id="foo" parameberClass="fooClass">
    {call
        declare
        dsc varchar(512);
        begin
    select
        count(*)
    into dsc
    from foo
    where birthday = TO_DATE(#birthday#, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        end
        }
</select>
```

birthday looks like '1999.11.11' and I can't change it, and yes birthday field is varchar not date and I can't change it either..

I get errors because of the `.` in `#birthday` string.

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 140:
PL/SQL: ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06550: line 1, column 48:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

I've tried quite a few different ways to prevent the error but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Why don't you convert the `birthday` column into a sql `DATE` and do your operations?

Comment: because that's not an option.. I'm adding a functionality to someone else's code which is already deployed.

Comment: You never said your constrains. How do you expect that we may know what could be your options? Seriously, you get free help in this site and you start being rude... Hope you find an answer.

Comment: @Luiggi: ? I stated the constraint in the OP..

Comment: You just said that you cannot change the data nor the type of the field. But I'm saying what about using `REPLACE` to replace those `.` by `-` and then converting the `birthday` column into sql `DATE` by using `TO_DATE`. I've never said change the type of the column, I've said **convert**,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> birthday field is varchar not date
>
> birthday = TO_DATE(#birthday#, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

This is wrong, you are **comparing a string with a date.** `birthday` column is **VARCHAR2 data type**, and you are comparing it with **TO_DATE** which converts a string into date.

Either use **TO_DATE** on both sides, or don't use at all.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH t(birthday) AS
  2    ( SELECT '1999.11.11' FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT COUNT(*)
  5  FROM t
  6  WHERE TO_DATE(birthday, 'YYYY.MM.DD') = TO_DATE('1999.11.11', 'YYYY.MM.DD');

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TO_CHAR` with mask:

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/943cf/1/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab(d VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO tab(d)
VALUES (TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY.MM.DD'));

/* or not sure exactly what you want */
INSERT INTO tab(d)
VALUES (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2015.09.10','YYYY.MM.DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))

SELECT *
FROM tab;
```

Comment: @eugene Please specify what suits you.